# Overriding property in shared project class

Tags: c#, inheritance, model-view-controller

Ok team,

Quick summary so you understand my question. We have an MVC app (Proj.MVC) that references a shared project (Shared.MVC). The shared project contains Controllers (BaseController & ApiController), Context, and Session Manager as those will be used by other projects. BaseController & ApiController have a reference to SharedContext and SharedSessionManager.

However, some project may need to add additional calls to Context and Session Manager. Now my problem is, I can use Interfaces so that new classes in Proj.MVC can swap out SharedContext with ProjContext and any inherited controllers can interchange the context type, but BaseController is still using SharedContext. Further all the Shared Controllers are using the SharedContext. So now 'new' logic is using the ProjContext & ProjSessionManager, while all the shared logic is using SharedContext & SharedSessionManager.

So my question is. How do I 'force' ProjContext/Session down to my Shared Controller? Pulling the Controllers out to Proj.MVC defeats the reuse.

```
namespace Shared.MVC
{
    public abstract class BaseMVCController: Controller
    {
        protected SharedContext DB;     
        protected SharedSessionManager SessionManager;
        
        protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            DB = new SharedContext();   //This is being triggered on startup. Likely because HomeController inherits from BaseMVCController
            SessionManager = new SharedSessionManager(DB);
        }
    }
    
    public abstract class SharedApiController : ApiController
    {
        protected ISharedContext DB;
        protected SharedSessionManager SessionManager;
        
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            DB = new SharedContext();
            SessionManager = new SharedSessionManager(DB);
        }
    }
    
    public class SharedSessionManager : ISessionManager
    {
        protected readonly ISharedContext DB;
        
        public SharedSessionManager()
        {
            DB = new SharedContext();
        }
        public SharedSessionManager(ISharedContext myContext)
        {
            DB = myContext;     //This is being called from the BaseMVCController.Initialize method
        }           
    }

    public class SharedContext : DbContext, ISharedContext
    {
       public SharedContext() : base("contextName")
       {
       }
       public virtual DbSet<MyType> MyList { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Post example code, very few people are going to get the idea you are explaining.

Comment: Hopefully the above helps. Basically all our controllers inherit from BaseMVCController. And everything works find as long as we use the basic SharedContext/SharedSessionManager.

In my case I want Proj.MVC to have it's own implementation of both, and for those instances to be assigned to BaseMVCController. That way everything in my Project is using ProjContext/ProjSessionManager

That said, I am fully aware (and ok with) the fact that anything inheriting from BaseMVCController will be limited to the methods identified in the interface.Only Proj.MVC would have access to the extra methods

Comment: you need to switch from manual db context initialization to dependency injection

Comment: Thanks. I'll start looking into DI. If you have any recommended links I'm open to them. Otherwise I'll be going through the Google :)

Comment: Follow up. So it appears SharedSessionManager is already configured for DI, but BaseMVCController is the injector (that part is good). Now it appears my problem is that BaseMVCController is hardset to use a SharedContext. So I have 2 questions. #1 How can I modify the BaseMVCController.Initialize to allow Constructor Injection (as that method only allows RequestContext)? and #2 I missed this in my earlier sample code, but SharedContext also inherits Entity.DbContext. So if I change BaseMVCController.DB to ISharedContext, it errors everywhere that a DbContext method is used.

Comment: I can not add DbContext to the ISharedContext interface, since it is not an interface itself.

Comment: I updated the example to include the current SharedContext structure. The issue I'm facing is since SharedContext currently implements DbContext, but DbContext isn't part of the interface many (dbContext) calls to ISharedContext fail. My initial approach was to make DbContext a property of ISharedContext. All calls were then updated to isharedContext.dbContext.someCall. However, my constructor then fails to properly setup SharedContext and it's associated tables.

Comment: As currently written, upon calling `public SharedContext(): base("myString")` the class is fully instantiated and all tables (like 'MyList') are fully populated. However, if I make DbContext a property and modify the constructor to `public SharedContext() { myDbContext = new DbContest("string");  }`, the table values like 'MyList' are never populated causing anything using them to fail. Intellisense tells me the `base("mystring")` is calling DbContext.DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString). So my modified call should be correct, yet the result of SharedContext instantiation is different.