# Dependency Injection getting new instance

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

So this question stems from a recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122746/overriding-property-in-shared-project-class). That led me into Dependency Injection, but now I have a very specific implementation question for DI. I am using what I believe would be Method Injection (via the DbFactory class below). Elsewhere in my code (external to namespace Shared) I set 'DbFactory.Db = new MyContext()'. The problem is that I set DbFactories Property, which is then used by various classes to instantiate their own instance of an ISharedContext BUT when one of those classes calls Dispose it disposes the DbFactory instance not it's local instance.

What I need is the ability for my 'main' program to set what type of DbContextes should be used (MyContext versus SharedContext), and for the Shared Library code (Shared.MVC) to create a new instance of ISharedContext based on the type set via dependency injection. However, it seems like instead I'm using DI to create a single instance for Shared.MVC to use, causing issues when one class versus another discards it.

Note I am just using basic .net (4.6) Dependency Injection. I don't have access to external libraries like Ninject or Unity.

```
namespace Shared.MVC
{
    public abstract class BaseMVCController: Controller
    {
        protected ISharedContext DB;     
        protected SharedSessionManager SessionManager;
        
        protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            DB = DbFactory.Db;    //new SharedContext();   
            SessionManager = new SharedSessionManager(DB);
        }
    }
    
    public abstract class SharedApiController : ApiController
    {
        protected ISharedContext DB;
        protected SharedSessionManager SessionManager;
        
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            DB = DbFactory.Db;    //new SharedContext();
            SessionManager = new SharedSessionManager(DB);
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            DB.Dispose();  //This ends up disposing DbFactory.Db, not the local copy.
        }
    }

    public class SharedContext : DbContext, ISharedContext
    {
       public SharedContext() : base("contextName")
       {
       }
    }

    public static class DbFactory
    {
        private static ISharedContext _dbContext;
        public static ISharedContext Db { 
            get { 
                    if(null == _dbContext) 
                        return new SharedContext();
                    else 
                        return _dbContext; //It appears this is returned by reference and anything getting this is using the same single instance
            } }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem you encounter is complete normal since the DbFactory is a singleton-alike-pattern.

Comment: I would recommend looking at this Stack Overflow https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359672 . The gist of it is that you don't need to dispose of your `DbContext`'s